# Fill in sequence within a group when sequence length and group size do not match

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
 > dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 3, 3, 3), week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
6, 3, 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

In human-readable form:

```
> df
   id week
1   1    1
2   1    2
3   1    3
4   1    4
5   1    5
6   1    6
7   1    7
8   1    8
9   2    1
10  2    2
11  2    3
12  2    4
13  2    5
14  2    6
15  3    3
16  3    4
17  3    5
```

I want to identify 4-week sequences within each id. For that, I want to generate the following data frame:

```
> df
   id week seq
1   1    1   1
2   1    2   2
3   1    3   3
4   1    4   4
5   1    5   1
6   1    6   2
7   1    7   3
8   1    8   4
9   2    1   1
10  2    2   2
11  2    3   3
12  2    4   4
13  2    5   1
14  2    6   2
15  3    3   1
16  3    4   2
17  3    5   3
```

I think I am looking for a way do a mutate where the input `seq(1, 4, 1)` is recycled within a group. My attempt below obviously fails because groups defined by id are of varying lengths. Any ideas, please?

```
df %>% arrange(id, week) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(seq = seq(1, 4, 1))
```

Comment: I realise that relying on recycling is a bad habit, but let's assume I want to do that in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `rep_len`. This will allow you to create your sequence vector and indicate the length (with is `n()` for each grouped `id` in this case).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  arrange(id, week) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(seq = rep_len(1:4, length.out = n()))
```

**Output**

```
      id  week   seq
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     1     1     1
 2     1     2     2
 3     1     3     3
 4     1     4     4
 5     1     5     1
 6     1     6     2
 7     1     7     3
 8     1     8     4
 9     2     1     1
10     2     2     2
11     2     3     3
12     2     4     4
13     2     5     1
14     2     6     2
15     3     3     1
16     3     4     2
17     3     5     3
```

Comment: I was certain that there is a base R function for doing what I want! I just got stuck when using the term "recycling" for googling. and `?rep_len` is not that clear either.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    arrange(id, week) %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(seq =  (row_number()-1) %% 4 + 1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
#      id  week   seq
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     1     2     2
# 3     1     3     3
# 4     1     4     4
# 5     1     5     1
# 6     1     6     2
# 7     1     7     3
# 8     1     8     4
# 9     2     1     1
#10     2     2     2
#11     2     3     3
#12     2     4     4
#13     2     5     1
#14     2     6     2
#15     3     3     1
#16     3     4     2
#17     3     5     3
```